# Service Worker is "installing" with every page reload though the sw.js did not change

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am using a service worker to cache the JS and CSS files of a web app.
I mostly use the code from a Google Chrome example, the only thing I added is a notification and countdown that refreshes the window when "new or updated content is available".

The Google example: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/5699e5d049235ef0f668e8e2aa3bf2646ba3872f/demo/app/js/service-worker-registration.js

However, this happens far too often and I don't understand why.
There has definitely not been any changes to the files on the server, but still sometimes I see the notification and the window reloads.

I expected this would only happen when any of the files governed by the service worker actually changes (they are all hashed via Webpack and have definitely not changed in between).

This is the code I use, inlined in `index.html`:

```
/* eslint-env browser */
'use strict';
function reloadApp(delay) {
  var t = delay || 0;
  var message = 'New or updated content is available. Reloading app in {s} seconds';
  var getMessage = function() { return message.replace('{s}', t) }
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'update-notification';
  div.innerHTML = getMessage();
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    t = t - 1;
    if (t <= 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
      div.innerHTML = getMessage();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {
    console.info('serviceWorker registered');
    reg.onupdatefound = function() {
      var installingWorker = reg.installing;
      installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
        switch (installingWorker.state) {
          case 'installed':
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              reloadApp(5);
            } else {
              console.log('Content is now available offline!');
            }
            break;

          case 'redundant':
            console.error('The installing service worker became redundant.');
            break;
        }
      };
    };
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
  });
}
```

This is the change I made:

```
switch (installingWorker.state) {
  case 'installed':
    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      // At this point, the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will
      // have been added to the cache.
      // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is available; please refresh."
      // message in the page's interface.
      console.log('New or updated content is available.');
    } else {
```

became:

```
switch (installingWorker.state) {
  case 'installed':
    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
      reloadApp(5);
```

The service worker itself is generated via `sw-precache-webpack-plugin` and the hashed files look like this:

```
var precacheConfig = [["cms.CrudFactory.144344a2.js","6a65526f764f3caa4b8c6e0b84c1b31b"],["cms.routes.c20796b4.js","f8018476ceffa8b8f6ec00b297a6492d"],["common.cms-main.0f2db9ff.js","92017e838aff992e9f47f721cb07b6f0"],["common.licensing-main.8000b17d.js","0d43abd063567d5edaccdcf9c0e4c362"],["common.mediaplayer-main.314be5d2.js","2061501465a56e82d968d7998b9ac364"],["common.ordering-main.783e8605.js","0531c4a90a0fa9ea63fbe1f82e86f8c6"],["common.shared-main.0224b0ea.js","956ae4d2ddbddb09fb51804c09c83b22"],["common.stores-main.98246b60.js","cbdc46bc3abeac89f37e8f64b1737a22"],["component.App.284fec19.js","07f1923f1a0098bf9eba28fc7b307c18"],["component.AppToolbar.00e371de.js","9b542d4a85bdeece9d36ee4e389f6206"],["component.DevToolbar.652bf856.js","1744126e32774a93796146ac878ddd8e"],["component.Grid.4b964e52.js","755819ca2c7f911805e372401d638351"],["component.MediaPlayer.54db6e85.js","d0d8ae269665e810d1b997b473005f76"],["component.Search.05476f89.js","0cae8928aff533a6726dfaeb0661456a"],["data.country-list.d54f29a7.js","e27746418e02f75593a93b958a60807e"],["dev.sendSlackMessage.da8e22f4.js","ccb10829f18a727b79a5e8631bc4b2a2"],["index.html","02ff43eabc33c600e98785cffe7597d9"],["lib.gemini-scrollbar.df2fbf63.js","3941036bacb4a1432d22151ea7da073b"],["lib.isotope-horizontal.1604d974.js","6ac56d4296468c4428b5b5301a65938a"],["lib.isotope-packery.fabb73c3.js","808061641596e4b0ea2158b42d65915a"],["lib.react-color.265a6de0.js","f23f63d7e6934e381ffdc0405ecb449a"],["lib.react-date-picker.0a81fec3.js","778d1626645e439ad01e182ee589971a"],["lib.react-select.c768cf77.js","c8782991a161790ef2c9a2c7677da313"],["main.43e29bc6.js","fe6a6277acaa2a369ef235961be7bbcf"],["route.admin.CleanupPage.8b4bbf8e.js","8ab20412329e1ba4adc327713135be97"],["route.app.CmsPage.8a4303fb.js","0bf1506869db24bb9789c8a46449c8ad"],["route.app.CmsPageWrapper.accdebcc.js","c91e77aa8b518e1878761269deac22b6"],["route.app.ContactPage.75693d32.js","a530b00a5230a44897c2bf0aa9f402a8"],["route.app.PasswordResetExpiredDialog.65431bae.js","b5eef791dbd68edd4769bd6da022a857"],["route.app.SeriesDetailsPage.11a6989b.js","c52178b57767ae1bf94a9594cb32718e"],["route.cms.MetadataFormsPage.636188d2.js","e1e592b7e3dd82af774ac215524465c0"],["route.cms.PermissionsListPage.0e1e3075.js","9a3cc340a64238a1ab3ba1c0d483b7bd"],["route.cms.PermissionsPage.78a69f60.js","4b18e646715d6268e7aba3932f4e04a9"],["route.cms.SysconfigPage.f699b871.js","79bd1275213478f2ff1970e0b7341c49"],["styles.43e29bc620615f854714.css","b2e9e55e9ee2def2ae577ee1aaebda8f"],["styles.e0c12bb1c77e645e92d3.css","626778177949d72221e83b601c6c2c0f"],["translations.en.83fced0e.js","7e5509c23b5aafc1744a28a85c2950bb"],["translations.nl.4ae0b3bb.js","515ec7be7352a0c61e4aba99f0014a39"],["vendor.e0c12bb1.js","36ce9e0a59c7b4577b2ac4a637cb4238"]];
var cacheName = 'sw-precache-v3-nisv-client-' + (self.registration ? self.registration.scope : '');
```

**Questions:**

- Why is the 'new or updated content' case happening so often?
- Is the assumption correct that `case 'installed': if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {` means `New or updated content is available`?
- How should I debug the problem?

Comment: 1. Does changing the static content, rehash the file, and trigger an update to your service worker?

2. Do you have `update on reload` checked?

Answer (score 3):

A service worker has a [life cycle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Basic_architecture):

```
- registered
- installing
- installed
- waiting
- activated
- redundant
```

When you register a service worker, it is fetched from the server, and it's lifespan in the `disk` cache depends on the `cache-control` response headers that your web server sends it with.

It is considered best practice, to have a `cache-control : no-store must-revalidate` along with a `max-age : 0` if possible.

If you forget, the service worker is usually considered `stale` after 24 hours of registration, and is `refetched` and disk caches updated.

There are **manual** upgrades you can do, by bumping up a `cache` version on the service worker, or changing the service worker code. Even a `byte` change makes the browser `view` the service worker as a new one, and it installs the new service worker.

This however, does not mean, the old service-worker is discarded. It is imperative that any user **close** all the tabs / **navigate** away from your site, for the browser to **discard** the old service worker, and **activate** the new one.

you can bypass this behavior, by a `self.skipWaiting` in your `install handler`

That said,

While developing, you have the option of opening the browser's (chromium)
dev panel, navigate to the `application` tab, and check the box that says

`update on reload`

What this does is, **immediately** discard the old service worker irregardless of whether there is a change in your service worker code.

Regarding your questions:

> - Is the assumption correct that case 'installed': if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) { means New or updated content is available?

NO. This means, that the new service worker, say sw-v1, is installed, and is currently `waiting` to activate.

> - Why is the 'new or updated content' case happening so often?

you say, you are using `sw-precache`. Since, I haven't used it myself, I have to add, a counter question

- Is the plugin configured, to pick up changes to your static assets, and automatically trigger a code change or a cache bump in your `service-worker` ?

If so, then, any new version of your service worker, must only be `waiting` and not `activating` on a change.

The probable reason for this `skipping` of the waiting stage is,

- you have a `self.skipWaiting` inside your `install` event inside your service  worker.

**Note** the above is true, ONLY if

- the change to your content happens. AND
- that change triggers a service worker update

In this scenario, you might want to consider commenting out the `self.skipWaiting` statement. Or, maybe you could configure your plugin, to not skip on update - this matters on your content, and you need to take a call

In lieu of the fact that your assets changed and/ or triggered an update,

The other (most probable) reason would have to be,

you have an `update on reload` box checked under the `application` - > `service workers` tab on your dev console.

Uncheck that box, if checked, and then clear all caches, unregister all workers. After , open a new tab and continue testing the behavior.